# Rails ассоциации двух моделей к одной?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ситуация такая, есть модель category и две модели product и article. Модель category может иметь много и products и много articles. Как объединить их таким образом, чтобы можно было вывести все products и все articles на странице categories/show, а также по отдельности?

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
    has_many :articles
    has_ancestry :orphan_strategy => :rootify

class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category

class Article < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать что-то такое:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
def show
 @category = Category.find(params[:id])
 @products = Product.where(category_id: @category.id)
 @articles = Article.where(category_id: @category.id)
end
```

И в представлении используйте переменные с нужными объектами, как необходимо

или (Rails Way) как посоветовал D-side

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
def show
 @category = Category.find(params[:id])
 @products = @category.products
 @articles = @category.articles
end
```

Comment: А что не так с `@category.products` и `@category.articles`? Суть ассоциаций же именно в том, чтобы завернуть связи уровня БД в нечто ООП-подобное.

Comment: А как на одной странице categories/show вывести и products и articles которые относятся к одной категории, чтоб они сортировались по имени или по дате в перемешку, а не сначала все products, а потом все articles ?